# inputting json to my http request in Swift and getting errors, but perfectly valid in jsonlint.com

Tags: json, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, jsonlint

So my goal is to be able to trigger a notification without getting a `NSCocoaErrorDomain` error. Before this issue, I sent a notification to my single device using this json data in the http request:

```
let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                       "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                       "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
    ]
```

This worked perfectly fine and is basically equivalent to the image below, but with a `notification` object added in. [image: Firebase docs]

Now I wanted to step up and send a notification to people subscribed to a topic, so I changed the code up a bit as well as the url, but when I pressed the button and the code ran, I got a `NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 3840` meaning my json was in an invalid format.

**NEW EDIT**So this is the function I use and the json I had in my http request:

```
func sendNotificationToUser(to topic: String, title: String, body: String) {
        
            let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myprojectnamehere-41f12/messages:send HTTP/1.1"
            guard let encodedURLString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed) else { return }
            let url = URL(string: encodedURLString)!
            let paramString: [String: Any] = [
                                               "message": [
                                                "topic" : topic,
                                                "notification" : [
                                                    "title": title,
                                                    "body": body
                                                ]
                                              ]
                                            ]
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("Bearer ya29.\(self.bearer)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let jsonData = data {
                        if let jsonDataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDictionary))")
                        }
                    }
                } catch let err as NSError {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        
    
}
```

So looking back I had to revamp my function above and change the parameters a bit, but now when the function is called...

```
getTheSchoolID { (id) in
            if let id = id {
                self.sendNotificationToUser(to: id, title: "New Event Added!", body: "A new event has been added to the dashboard!!")

            }
        }
```

I get this error in the debug console:

[image: error]

I wanted it to basically equal to this code snippet in the Firebase docs:
[image: json topics]

So I decided to head over to [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) and validate it. I replaced the square brackets with curly brackets, put double-quotes on `id`, `body`, and `title`, and the json was perfectly valid, but when I run it in Swift, it says it's invalid. The `id, body,` and `title` in my HTTP request are all String format, and I used two out of those 3 variables in the first json data I posted above and it worked perfectly fine, so I can't figure out why the console isn't picking up on the JSON. If anyone can help me figure this out, that would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: I don't like that the name is `paramString` of your var. How do you use it? I hope you use `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Unreleated avoid using NS(Mutable)Stuff when Stuff is available => ` let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)` => `let request = URLRequest(url: url), and you can remove `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments`, it's useless in your case.

Comment: Where exacly did you get `NSCocoaErrorDomain Code = 3840`? Dont print `print(err.debugDescription)`, print `err` instead. Also, that's the line? It means then that the issue is about the response not being JSON, but what's the response? Could you print also `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` when it fails?.

Comment: Have you tried using the `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder` in Swift? It's part of `Foundation`.

Comment: "No value", but is the response code 200? Could it be that in case of success for that API call there is no return value?

Comment: No the response code is still 404 when I print the `String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)` and see the data in the console. @Larme